# ContentProvider usage

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

**A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications.**

Is this the only purpose of using it? What about simply getting data from the WS and writing it in the CP and then reading from here in Activities?

What about [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/sync/):
CP is used here to share a database for several apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just can achive that  with a database, but I strong recommend the use of contentprovider even if you are not going to share data between aplications. classes such as CursorLoader (correction) load directly datas from contentprovider, if you use just a database you have to extend this class to get the same performance 
so to conclude it's all made for working with contentprovider.

Comment: So the sentence from the doc :"A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications." is not true,right?

Comment: is not true. in fact you can declare the conentprovider in the manifest as  private so you can force it to not share data.

Comment: @barn.gumbl: The key word in your quoted sentence is "required". If you wish to share a database across app, then a `ContentProvider` is required. It is not required for use within a single app. It *can* be used within a single app, but it is not *required*. Hence, the quoted sentence is true, in the context of the paragraph from the documentation from which you pulled it.

Comment: @Xenione: "classes such as Loader load directly datas from contentprovider" -- no, it does not. `Loader` is an abstract class and does not do much of anything "directly". `CursorLoader` loads data from a `ContentProvider`. [My `SQLiteCursorLoader`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) loads data directly from SQLite, without a `ContentProvider`. "if you use just a database you have to extend this class to get the same performance " -- or you can use any number of other techniques, such as accessing the database from your own thread.

Comment: what I meant it's that It is easer  ( you have to write less code) to work with contentProviders and the perfect example is the cursorLoader, with content provider is easy and short of course you can use just a database but you have to extend cursorloader and implement de access to the database is not too much harder but it's not more direct as conentprovider is.